# .net on target pc running mono app

Tags: .net, mono, monodevelop

I'm a newbie on monodevelop, had problems with Microsoft.net framework availability on target pc, so can I use mono to build a program for a pc which doesn't have.net framework, for example, windows XP?

Comment: You can install .net framework 3.5 on Windows XP.

Comment: I don't want to install any prerequisites, especially .Net - the problem is about it's size, 2MB apps become 57 MB packages - Most libraries which are useless for my app.

Comment: Any .net application requires the .net or mono Framework to run. If you don't want any prerequisite on A PC without mono or .net installed (e.g. under Windows XP or Linux distribution such as RedHat or CentOS), forget it.

Comment: Is there anyway to build a "desktop" app which doesn't required perquisites or even we include a part of these frameworks [I KNOW IT'S NOT POSSIBLE FOR .Net]?

Comment: Have a look to [this article](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/)

Comment: that article helped a lot Graffito, Thanks. I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions in this article: [Embedding Mono at mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/).

It needs some time to configure it for your selected "Platform" when using Mono.